# how to make the coverflow effect of the original iOS music app using Swiper js?

Tags: ios, swiper.js, audio-player, coverflow

So I'm making a small project of a web music player, and I want to recreate the coverflow effect of the original iOS ipod app [iOS coverflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuDHw.png)

However I haven't be able to make the effect the same, the issue is with the slides on the side, how do I make them the same angle?
here is my code and image:

```
   var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
      effect: "coverflow",
          slidesPerGroup: 1, 
    slidesPerView: 1,
    grabCursor: true,
    spaceBetween: -16,
    autoHeight: false,
    preloadImages: true,
    loop: true,
    createElements: false,
    centeredSlides: true,
    coverflowEffect: {
      scale: 1,
      stretch: 0,
      depth: 200,
      modifier: 0.75,
      slideShadows: true,
    },
```

[my coverflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LODZ9.png)

I tried with the modifier or rotate, but still with no results